# Can I post json object from model class to angular .ts file

Tags: asp.net, angular, typescript

I am retrieving XML result from thrid-party API to ASP.net web API. Now I want to send this retrieved XML( converted in JSON) to angular typescript file. How can I achieve it?

My approach 1. send JSON from model class to controller and then from the controller to angular service or component's .ts file. 
2.post from model class to component's .ts file.

```
     var objJson = new JavaScriptSerializer().Serialize(responseB);
     var response = await client.PostAsync("http://localhost:4200/add", new StringContent(objJson, Encoding.UTF8, "application/json"));
     var responseString = await response.Content.ReadAsStringAsync();
```

Answer (score 0):

You can't send something "from a WebAPI to a TypeScript file".

It sounds like you want to send it from the server to a client app in a web browser? If this is the case, then you need the client app to ask for it, or to push it to the client.

If the client initiated the request that had you fetch this resource, then you could send it in the response to the client.

If the client app has some bi-directional connection to your server like [socket.io](https://socket.io/) or [SignalR](https://github.com/SignalR/SignalR), you can send it over that.

Or, depending on the frequency, probability of this happening, you might have the client poll for it.

But it all depends on the state machine of the entire process you are implementing. Does the client app initiate any of this, or this an event that the client does not initiate, but needs to be informed of? If this is the case, you either need to poll or to set up a connection from the client to the server.